# Placement of Sign-Up Forms on a Landing Page

Tags: forms, interaction-design, user-behavior

I am creating a series of landing pages for our organization for people to sign up to receive various services. In a discussion with our team, the idea was floating around to place our sign up form immediately following the hero image/header instead of after a description of the planned service.

My natural inclination would be to place the sign up forms towards the bottom of the page after the description instead of near the top, especially since a) most every other website I've seen in the past does this and b) it feels more logical, however they insisted they wanted the forms be placed at the top of the landing pages. After a few minutes of searching and looking around, I couldn't find much as to the pros/cons of placing the sign up form at the top or bottom of a landing page. The question is: Generally speaking, what would be better for users: placing the forms at the top or at the bottom of the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A / B test it to make sure.It depends on what you are offering, how people reach the website and the type of traffic you are having.

If people know your product and they visit your website they migh fill the form immediately. Other would need to find out more ... and usually this is the case. Understanding your offer and gaining some trust before submitting their data.